# HTML5 video does not play on safari via online server

Tags: html, video, safari, html5-video, mp4

I'm using the [jquery.videoBg](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/) to display a background html5 video on a site. In the current stage, I'm still using the sample video provided.

I have added the following to the root htaccess

```
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

When testing this out locally, everything works fine. When testing from the offical plugin site, everything works fine. Testing from the deployment server though, it breaks in safari. It even breaks when directly requesting the video, safari just shows me the following image:

[image: screenshot]

To recap;

- problem isn't the html/js code since it also happens when requesting directly
- video works fine served from localhost
- video works fine server from someone else's host
- video *breaks* when serving from my client's host (which I am not allowed to link to)

I couldn't find any help on this specific issue while searching SO or the goog.

Has anyone experienced issues while serving a mp4 video, or has any idea what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer not long after posting this question. 
I hope it helps someone out.

Turns out Safari didn't like the use of .htpasswd HTTP authentication. After adding the following to the .htaccess the video worked fine;

```
<FilesMatch mp4>
Satisfy any
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The video is now publicly accessible though, but that is not a problem in my specific case.

Comment: I still have the problem from https. I'm on Ruby on Rails/Passenger, and, unlike http requests, the https ones hit rails instead of accessing the video file in my public folder.